# How Do I use Angular 4 Dialog Directives?

Tags: angular-material2

I am developing an Angular web application using:

- Angular 4.1.2
- Angular Material 2.0.0-beta.11

I am trying to create a simple modal dialog and on reading the Angular guide documents ([Dialog | Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)) I see that there are several directives available to make it easier to structure the dialog content.

I cannot work out how to implement `md-dialog-title`, `<md-dialog-content>`, `<md-dialog-actions>` or `md-dialog-close`. The attributes, when applied to an element, appear to make no difference at all and the `<md-dialog-content>` and `<md-dialog-actions>` create errors like this:

`Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: 'md-dialog-content' is not a known element:`

Any guidance would be very welcome please. Here are some further details of my project:

For my initial development I have created an Angular module, named `AngularMaterialModule` to manage my Angular Materials. Here is a summary of it:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {
  MdAutocompleteModule,
  MdButtonModule,
  ....
  MdStepperModule,
  StyleModule,
} from '@angular/material';
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk/table';
import { A11yModule } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import { BidiModule } from '@angular/cdk/bidi';
import { OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
import { PlatformModule } from '@angular/cdk/platform';
import { ObserversModule } from '@angular/cdk/observers';
import { PortalModule } from '@angular/cdk/portal';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    // Material Modules
    MdAutocompleteModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    ....
    PlatformModule,
    PortalModule
    ],
  declarations: []
})
export class AngularMaterialModule { }
```

My Visual Studio Solution was created using `dotnet new angular` taking advantage of the Microsoft ASP.Net SPA Templates.

In my `app.module.client.ts` file I import the `AngularMaterialModule`, described above, like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';


import { AngularMaterialModule } from './core/angular-material.module';
import { sharedConfig } from './app.module.shared';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: sharedConfig.bootstrap,
    declarations: sharedConfig.declarations,
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AngularMaterialModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        ...sharedConfig.imports
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the actual dialog module into the module you want to use it in.

```
import { MdDialogModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MdDialogModule
  ],
})
```

After that, it's a straight forward and follow the example in their docs

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef, MD_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';

/**
 * @title Dialog Overview
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example.html'
})
export class DialogOverviewExample {

  animal: string;
  name: string;

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog) {}

  openDialog(): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: { name: this.name, animal: this.animal }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      this.animal = result;
    });
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MD_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

If you ever want to create a custom dialog component, you will have to add it into your `entryComponents` in the module.

```
import { MdDialogModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
 entryComponents: [
    AddressDialogComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    MdDialogModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    AddressDialogComponent,
  ],
})
```